Isolated css in Blazor .net 8 WASM didn't work
I have a solution as described in title.
(I'm new in blazor) I worked few times on new solution. On one day, before close solution css works fine. Next day when I start solution, it didn't see css. Then I created the new one and problem repeated.
I found here post, where somebody propose to add in the api project, parameter to method
app.UseStaticFiles("/styles"); and in the App.razor to complete paths to css.
Then it worked.
But now, when I added css to component and page it didn't works.
What can be wrong in solution?

Normally speaking, when we faced issue like: it worked before and I didn't make any changes on the app, but now it doesn't work, we always clean and rebuild the app and run the app to see whether the issue still exist. If still exsit, then let's make sure whether there's someone else update the code or configurations. If no, or can't find, then we start troubleshooting the issue. Here what trapped us is the css isolation.

For blazor wasm app, could you pls check whether there's <link href="{ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">(ASSEMBLY NAME shall be your project name) in your index.html file? Because CSS isolation occurred at build time and the style you write incomponantName.razor.css will be compiled into projectName.style.css and this file can be seen when we load the page.

Thank You for reply. No one works on the app except me. In the git (git = github; standard configuration from VS 2024 for git; windows 10 installed on June) I haven't any changes. I was cleaning, reabuilding application many times, without any result. I even deleted it by hand all obj, bin (folders) and user.proj files. All files are correctly named. I was looking in the Internet for solution, but I didn't found it. App is Blazor Web App. Link is named projectName.styles.css

could you pls share a minimal sample for reproducing the issue?

I can't reproduce your issue in my side, I worked on a .net 8 blazor web app interactive server render mode, and everything worked well. Could you please help check in browser console window about whether the class name is set correctly and whether the class is attached, https://i.sstatic.net/QSTm5YnZ.png and whether the projectName.style.css is loaded into the browser? https://i.sstatic.net/3Gch5MMl.png

From the beggining I got errors in webbrowser console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () for KS24.styles.css:1, app.css:1, favicon.png:1
The mark b-something is added to html, but there is no class in css.
Only bootstrap is loaded.
I can share all project to You, but not in public. Is there some possibility to make it? If yes, You can find contact to me in my profile.

hmmm, you'd better not to share the complete project.... A minimal sample shall be better. Since we had a 400 error in console window, there might be something wrong within your project, and I'm afraid even if you share the whole project, it will be hard to narrow down the issue. If you are completely sure that you didn't make any changes in your project and the issue occurred all of a sudden, it might also relate to the environment. If it possible, can you please create a new project to see whether CSS isolation worked? And if possible, do you have another computer to test your project?
